# Sliver not allowing to set Max Width of Container?

Tags: flutter, responsive, nestedscrollview, sliverappbar, customscrollview

I am trying to make a responsive page that works well on Mobile and Desktop. I am using SliverAppBar inside NestedScrollView. The issue is maxwidth constraints to a container are totally ignored in NestedScrollView. This behavior is also same with CustomScrollView.

How to restrict the size of Container in NestedScrollView body widget.

Below is the code:

```
import "dart:math";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class ResponsiveSliver extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'responsive-sliver';

  @override
  _ResponsiveSliverState createState() => _ResponsiveSliverState();
}

class _ResponsiveSliverState extends State<ResponsiveSliver> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(
                "Responsive Sliver",
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
          child: Container(
            child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, child) => Divider(
                height: 1,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
                  height: 100,
                  // width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

In my code above you can notice is am using maxWidth constraints,

```
ConstrainedBox( constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200), child: ())
```

and

```
Container( constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200), child: (),)
```

But these maxWidth constraints are completely ignored and it takes full width of the available screen.

I want to make NestedScrollView of full screen width which thus makes SliverAppbar cover whole screen width.

So far, I understand the Constraints take the width based on the size of their parent. In this case parent NestedScrollView is taking full screen width and is thus ignoring ConstrainedBox maxWidth property.

So how to make SliverAppBar full width in size and still set Max. Width on a Container?

Please advice how to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: check [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: @pskink I understand the constraints are based on size of parent widget and that is why it is ignored. But how do we restrict size of parent nestredscrollview, especially with sliverappbar needs to take whole screen width?

Comment: everything is explained in the link i posted: check the examples they provide - you dont need all of them (29) - just first 10 - 12 is enough, the sources are here: https://github.com/marcglasberg/flutter_layout_article

Comment: @pskink the issue is not about constraints, but using constraints with slivers. I have updated the question. See if it makes sense

Comment: I tested above code in emulator mobile and on web. It does not respect constraints on my end.

Answer (score 3):

Any scrollable widget by default forces the child to expand and doesn't care about its horizontal constraints unless you constrain the scrollable widget.

However, in most cases you'll want to only constrain the child. There are few ways to do that here but the best will wrapping it in an `UnconstrainedBox`.

```
import "dart:math";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class ResponsiveSliver extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'responsive-sliver';

  const ResponsiveSliver({super.key});

  @override
  State<ResponsiveSliver> createState() => _ResponsiveSliverState();
}

class _ResponsiveSliverState extends State<ResponsiveSliver> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            const SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(
                "Responsive Sliver",
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: UnconstrainedBox(
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, child) => const Divider(
                height: 1,
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

It simply does the opposite of the `ConstrainedBox`. Instead of forcing constraints, it doesn't impose any incoming constraints i.e from `ListView, NestedScrollView, CustomSrollView` etc. but allows the child to lay itself using its own constraints.

Refer to [Flutter Documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UnconstrainedBox-class.html) which explicitly indicates that

> A widget that imposes no constraints on its child, allowing it to render at its "natural" size.

> This allows a child to render at the size it would render if it were alone on an infinite canvas with no constraints. This container will then attempt to adopt the same size, within the limits of its own constraints. If it ends up with a different size, it will align the child based on alignment. If the box cannot expand enough to accommodate the entire child, the child will be clipped.

> In debug mode, if the child overflows the container, a warning will be printed on the console, and black and yellow striped areas will appear where the overflow occurs.

Surprisingly(or as intended), it works without any issues as long as your child doesn't overflow. A hidden gem indeed.

However, I couldn't have found this solution without [Mustafa Tahir](https://medium.com/@mustafatahirhussein)'s article in medium. You can find it [here](https://medium.com/@mustafatahirhussein/the-containers-width-does-not-reflect-inside-a-listview-in-flutter-fixed-64cc2e73e287) for more ways. Though I liked this one best as it is clean.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using padding instead of a BoxConstraint.

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConstrainedSliverWidth extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double maxWidth;
  const ConstrainedSliverWidth({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.maxWidth,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var padding = (size.width - maxWidth) / 2;
    return Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: max(padding, 0)),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

If you replace `ConstrainedBox` with `ConstrainedSliverWidth` it should work.